# Execute `<Plug>` map for Vim through terminal/command-line, as startup arguments

Tags: vim, macvim, vim-plugin

I am using `vimwiki`, a plugin for Vim, on a daily basis; and I am wondering if I can trigger its `<Plug>` mapping "`<Plug>VimwikiMakeDiaryNote`" through terminal/command-line arguments? I have found the particular command is defined as follows:

```
command! -count=1 VimwikiMakeDiaryNote
  \ call vimwiki#diary#make_note(v:count1)
```

The `<Plug>` mapping is defined as:

```
if !hasmapto('<Plug>VimwikiMakeDiaryNote')
 exe 'nmap <silent><unique> '.g:vimwiki_map_prefix.'<Leader>w <Plug>VimwikiMakeDiaryNote'
endif
nnoremap <unique><script> <Plug>VimwikiMakeDiaryNote :VimwikiMakeDiaryNote<CR>
```

Is there a way to trigger the command/mapping `VimwikiMakeDiaryNote` through terminal/command-line, by passing *something* as arguments for Vim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the `<Plug>`-mapping simply invokes the eponymous command, it's easiest to invoke the command directly. You can execute arbitrary Ex commands with the `-c {command}` or `+{command}` option:

```
$ vim +VimwikiMakeDiaryNote
```

### Adoption on Windows & Linux OS

#### On Windows: use [AutoHotKey](http://ahkscript.org/)

Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> shall either start Gvim, or loop through all existing instances of Gvim.

```
#i::
IfWinExist ahk_class Vim
    groupactivate, VIM, r
else
    run C:\Vim\vim80\gvim.exe, +VimwikiMakeDiaryNote, max
return
+#i:: run C:\Vim\vim80\gvim.exe +VimwikiMakeDiaryNote, , max
```

#### On Linux

Added the following entry to `~/.bashrc`

```
alias v='vim +VimwikiMakeDiaryNote'
```

Comment: Fantastic, this works like a breeze. Hope you don't mind my edits on your answer (what I have eventually implemented on my machines).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, the easiest way is to test an environment variable, e.g.:

```
if !empty($VIM_WIKI)
  " Your mappings...
endif
```

The mappings will be applied, if `VIM_WIKI` environment variable is not empty:

```
VIM_WIKI=1 vim file
```

Comment: Hi Ruslan, I don't quite follow your answer. Ingo's response directly answered my question. Thank you as well!!

Comment: @llinfeng, you can pass environment variables to any program by prepending space-separated `key=value` pairs: `A=1 B=2 C=3 command args`. So you can pass an environment variable to `vim` and process the `vimrc` according to its value. If, for example, `VIM_WIKI` variable is set, then you can assign mappings, otherwise skip them at all (maybe using them for another file type).

Comment: @llinfeng, I doubt it it easiest to remember `+VimwikiMakeDiaryNote` than `VIM_WIKI=1`. Of course, you can make a command alias... if you like.

Comment: Looks cool; where, then, shall I drop the `if ... endif` definitions you mentioned in the beginning? In my `.vimrc`? Or, somewhere else that is globally accessible? Thx!

Comment: The `if` block is supposed to wrap the lines in `vimrc` (the lines you want to keep in "vim wiki" mode)

Comment: Get you. Thanks a lot!